# Сравнение высоты и ширины элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хочу сделать условие, при котором в консоль браузера будет выводиться текст в зависимости от ориентации изображения.

Придумал только так:

```js
var img = $("img");
var w = img.width;
var h = img.height;

if (w > h) {
  console.log('horizontal');
}
if (w = h) {
  console.log('quadro');
}
if (w < h) {
  console.log('vertical');
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x300"  alt="">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Но какое бы изображение я ни вставил, в консоль всегда выводится `quadro`.

Правильно ли я это делаю? Возможно ли вообще это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы используете jQuery, однако доступ к высоте и ширине хотите получить как в plain JavaScript. В jQuery используются функции `elem.width()` и `elem.height()`

И еще: операторы сравнения в JS - `==` и `===` (строгое равенство). А у вас `=` присваивание, которое всегда истинно во втором условии